# How do I trigger the Drop event with jQuery UI Droppable without actually dragging and dropping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I have a **droppable** with a drop event handler:

```
$(this).droppable({
  drop:function(){
    console.log('OMG You Dropped It!');
  }
});
```

I have a **draggable**:

```
$(this).draggable();
```

What I want to do is trigger the drop event handler on the **droppable** without actually dragging and dropping the **draggable**. I want to simulate the actual behavior without physically performing the behavior.

I thought something like this would do:

```
$(droppable).trigger('drop', [draggable]);
```

Unfortunately, it's not quite that simple. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284621/278405?programmatically-drag-and-drop-element-onto-another-element

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should move the code in your `drop` handler to a separate function.
You can then call the function both in the handler and elsewhere.

Comment: The above is simplified sample code to illustrate what I want to accomplish, not *the* code.

Anyway, how would this resolve my issue?

Comment: You can call the function instead of triggering the event.

Answer (score 9):

You can trigger the function associated with the drop call via the option-method:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            do stuff }
    });
var drop_function = $("#droppable").droppable.option('drop');
drop_function();
```

This way you get whatever would happen when dropping something on droppable. Of course you could just execute the function instead of assigning it.
It's nonetheless a good idea to assign a function to drop, that you define somewhere else, just for clarities sake.

Comment: +1 for being able to call outside of scope of the original function definition (e.g.) during a QUnit test.

Comment: New syntax is: $("#droppable").droppable('option', 'drop').

Comment: @StuperUser i don't get it. how does the $("#droppable") know which element was dragged and droped on it?

Comment: In the 'drop' event handler function for the droppable, the dropped element is: `ui.draggable`. Check the drop event: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop for more details.

Comment: @StuperUser How do you init both of the params during function call? drop_function('event','ui-draggable');

Comment: @Roylee You don't init them, the jQueryUI code that raises the events passes the event object and the ui object to the function. The ui object contains draggable as a member `ui.draggable`.

Comment: @StuperUser yeah, now we are trying to simulate/take into control instead of letting it happened automatically. That's why you let the drop_function be called outside.

Comment: I see now. Since the params are just objects passed to the function, depending on what your `drop_function` does (how it uses the event and ui params), populating it with an object with a member called draggable e.g. `{ draggable : $('#elementYouWantToPassId')[0] }`, then when you call that function, you'll use that object and the draggable.

Comment: In my case, `element.draggable('option', 'drag')();`

Comment: Any chance someone can update this for 2014? I'm trying some of the examples in the comments but still can't quite figure out the syntax for triggering a drop.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by `StuperUser` and based on `ajmurmann`'s answer, with the **recent versions of jQuery** you should do:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        do stuff }
});
var drop_function = $("#droppable").droppable('option', 'drop');
drop_function();
```