# jQuery UI Drag and Drop with .trigger()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, triggers, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to 'trigger' a drag and drop manually without the interaction of a mouse/user.

So far I have been able to setup the jQuery UI [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) for drag and drop but unable to trigger the drag and drop using the trigger() method.

Can anyone help with setting this up?

My code so far is:

```
  $(function() {
      $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
      $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
        .find( "p" )
        .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });

    $('#draggable').trigger("drop", $('#droppable'));
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**To make things simpler**. All I want to be able to do is call the 'drop' method from anywhere outside of the droppable() but I will always need to be able to specify the event and ui objects.

Comment: This isn't an answer, I just don't understand your question. What event is going to make the drag and drop happen if not some interaction with a user?

Comment: There is no specific "event". I just need to simulate the drag and drop process and any functions which occur after the drop - as if the user was actually dragging and dropping. Think of it as Opening a saved file...

Comment: possibly dupe of [How do I trigger the Drop event with jQuery UI Droppable without actually dragging and dropping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188130/how-do-i-trigger-the-drop-event-with-jquery-ui-droppable-without-actually-draggin)

Comment: It does say to create a var drop_function = $("#droppable").droppable('option', 'drop'); drop_function(); but where do I reference #draggable in this function?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I find myself asking the exact same thing at the moment!

Comment: Neither found a solution, but feel free to play around with http://jsfiddle.net/tW638/ , which simply contains the above JS code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284621/278405?programmatically-drag-and-drop-element-onto-another-element

Answer (score 2):

Why not to create a custom event trigered by the drop? So you can trigger it yourself:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).trigger("customEvent", ui);
        }
    });
    $( "#droppable" ).bind("customEvent", function(event, ui ){         
        $( this )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!");
    });  
   $( "#droppable" ).trigger("customEvent", $( "#draggable" ));  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
$('#droppable').trigger('drop', $('#draggable'));
```

But even then, I wonder if the draggable element will make its way to the droppable as what got dropped...

Comment: I can't seem this to trigger a drop on the droppable. No console error, but no triggered drop event, either.