# Trigger a drop when a draggable is moved outside a droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

When the dragged `<li>` is out of the droppable `#div1`, how can I force the dragged `<li>` to drop?

```
$("li").draggable();

$("#div1").droppable({  
    tolerance:'pointer',
    drop:function (event,ui) {
        alert("dropped")
    },
    out:function (event,ui){
        //if out then drop the li
    }               
});
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML as well please?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188130/how-do-i-trigger-the-drop-event-with-jquery-ui-droppable-without-actually-draggi) 
it is best to create a function of whatever it is you want to do when a li is dropped and you just call that function.