# Drop draggable on droppable programmatically and trigger drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Just like in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/95Wej/ I have some elements (draggables) which I want to **programmatically** (just by code, no user interaction) move to their corresponding droppables. This I can do.

What I don't know is why .droppable("drop") event isn't firing up.
**I need droppable to register that it has draggable on it.** Otherwise (in my more complex setup) there is some strange behavior when user moves that draggable.

I tried to `.trigger("mousemove"), mousedown`, reinitialize `.droppable()` after `.position()`, but none of that helped.

**EDIT:**
"Strange" behavior was caused by maintaining `position:relative;`, which I solved by setting it to absolute before calling `.position()`.
Nevertheless the question about why the event isn't fired remains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I trigger the Drop event with jQuery UI Droppable without actually dragging and dropping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188130/how-do-i-trigger-the-drop-event-with-jquery-ui-droppable-without-actually-draggi)

Comment: Checkout the second answer, it should give you what you need.

Comment: Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/95Wej/4/

Comment: @apaul34208 Thank you for showing the way. But I can't access the draggable (`ui` element) by calling the `.droppable('option', 'drop')` function as suggested; console.log is telling me that `ui is undefined`. Here is my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/95Wej/6/  Do you know why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284621/278405?programmatically-drag-and-drop-element-onto-another-element

Answer (score 2):

The *drop* event handler on `droppable`s is a bit strange. If you initialize the `droppable` with an event handler for the *drop* event like so:

```
$('div.droppable').droppable({drop: dropFn});
```

Then `dropFn` is the only function that gets called when an element is dropped on the `droppable` and you can't get it to be called using just the `.trigger` method. Instead, what you need to do is initialize the `droppable` without an event handler for the drop function and then bind the event handler for the *drop* event later like so:

```
$('div.droppable').droppable().on('drop', dropFn);
```

User initiated drops won't be affected but now you can trigger the drop event in your code. When you do this you have to provide a substitute for the `ui` object described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) like so:

```
$('div.droppable').first().trigger('drop', {draggable: ..., helper: ...});
```

I achieve moving the `draggable` to the `droppable` by setting the position of the `droppable` to "relative", dynamically (using a call to `.css`) setting the following CSS on the `draggable` to the following:

```
div.draggable {
    position: absolute;
    left:     0;
    top:      0;
}
```

And then detaching and appending the `draggable` to the `droppable`:

```
$('div.draggable').first().detach().appendTo($('div.droppable').first());
```

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279352/1852838.

In my examples I always used the first `draggable` or `droppable` but you should be able to adjust this to your specific application easily.

Answer (score 0):

Its not firing becouse you are not droping and element there. You are using the `.position` function of jquery to move the dragable into the dropable. So your goal is to use the callback of moving function.

```
$(this).position({
  of: "." + $(this).data("target")
}, function(){
  //do some stuff
});
```

Becouse you are inside an `.each` loop this callback function is fired multiple times.

Comment: No, my goal is to use already defined .droppable("drop") function. I'd like to avoid redefining it, although it seems like the only solution so far because I can't access the `ui` object of that function as suggested by @StuperUser in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3647016/836697.