# How do I make a JavaScript event trigger after a draggable object in jQuery has reached a certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am fairly new to programming in general. Recently, I have started learning jQuery and I have tried making a little 'game' with it. However, I can not find  an answer anywhere on how to make a jQuery object trigger a JavaScript event.

My code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        confirm("Are you ready for your race?")
var snd = new Audio("rev1.mp3");
snd.play();

$(function() {
$("#car").draggable();
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="car">
            <div id="top"></div>
            <div id="bottom"></div>
            <div id="fwheel"></div>
            <div id="bwheel"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="line">
        <div id="line1"><img src="#"></div>
        <div id="line2"><img src="#"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do here is when the object (which is the div id 'car') reaches 'line2', an alert pops up and a sound plays, but I am not sure how to make that happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding line2 as droppable

http://plnkr.co/edit/yDMZdXLUc4FV5lMrNYsM?p=preview

```
  $(function() {
    var hasReached = false;

    $("#car").draggable();

    $("#line2").droppable({over: function(){
      if(!hasReached){
        alert("Tada!!!");
        hasReached=true;
      }
      console.log("over line 2");
    }})

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even track the `x and y co-ordinate` of the draggable div

```
$('#car').draggable(
    {
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
           //check it is over the line and show alert
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use the same answer than the one given here:

[How do I trigger the Drop event with jQuery UI Droppable without actually dragging and dropping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188130/how-do-i-trigger-the-drop-event-with-jquery-ui-droppable-without-actually-draggi)

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            do stuff }
    }); var drop_function = $("#droppable").droppable.option('drop'); drop_function();
```

Comment: You should mark the question as a duplicate in that case.